# Pandas: I have a ValueError: could not convert string to float: '72,100.00'. How do I fix this?

Tags: python, pandas, string, valueerror

Pandas, `DataFrame`

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '72,100.00'
```

I tried this:

```
import numpy as np
from decimal import Decimal
#dollars_dec = Decimal(dollars.strip('$'))
df['prijs_per_nacht'] = df['prijs_per_nacht'].apply(lambda x: float(x.split()[0].replace('$', '')))
```